# How to read/write files with python3 from/in hadoop cluster when hadoop and python are in different docker containers?

Tags: python-3.x, hadoop, docker-compose

I hade a docker container running a hadoop cluster and another docker container running python scripts. How do I read/write files from python container from/to hadoop container ? Q.Q

Answer (score 0):

You have to expose the services running in your docker container on the network so that other services running outside or in another container can access the resources.

In DockerFile, you should expose the Namenodes and datanodes port by adding the expose argument with port numbers :

```
EXPOSE  <port no1> <port no2>...
```

In order to understand in detail, please read :

https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/#communicating-to-the-outside-world